# Why I get some strange chars when I deploy with Helm via the command line?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

I am trying to deploy [the nginx-ingress helm chart](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services.md) and I want to provide some `extraArgs`.

The thing is that, when I try to pass the arguments from the console

```
helm upgrade --install ${release_name} \
--set controller.extraArgs={udp-services-configmap=default/cm-udp-services} \
stable/nginx-ingress
```

I get this when I `describe` the deployment.

```
    Args:
      /nginx-ingress-controller
      --default-backend-service=default/tcp-udp-ic-nginx-ingress-default-backend
      --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
      --ingress-class=nginx
      --configmap=default/tcp-udp-ic-nginx-ingress-controller
      --0=udp-services-configmap:default/cm-udp-services
```

I just don't understand why I get this **0=**.

However, when I add the extra argument via the `values.yml` file,

```
  ## Additional command line arguments to pass to nginx-ingress-controller
  ## E.g. to specify the default SSL certificate you can use
  ## extraArgs:
  ##   default-ssl-certificate: "<namespace>/<secret_name>"
  extraArgs: {
               udp-services-configmap=default/cm-udp-services
  }
```

everything is ok.

Has anyone else encounter this?

**EDIT**

Even though weibeld's answer solved the problem, I observe that when I deploy the IC, the service unfortunately does not have the ports that are stated in the config-map open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the curly braces and delimit the `udp-services-configmap` argument with a period:

```
helm upgrade --install ${release_name} \
--set controller.extraArgs.udp-services-configmap=default/cm-udp-services \
stable/nginx-ingress
```

And if you use a `values.yaml` file, the usual way to write it is:

```
controller:
  extraArgs:
    udp-services-configmap: default/cm-udp-services
```

You don't need curly braces in YAML, except for denoting an empty object (`extraArgs: {}`).